# How can I use a Session attribute saved from a Check in an SSE request in Gatling?

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

**See working Java code at bottom.**

I'm trying to create an SSE connection testing scenario that uses a client ID that is the response to a previous REST POST call. Here's the Scala code:

```scala
package computerdatabase

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

class ssetest extends Simulation {

  val registration = scenario("registration")
    .exec(http("endpoint1")
      .post("http://localhost:7070/api/register")
      .body(RawFileBody("./Stocks.json")).asJson
      .check(status is 201)
      .check(jsonPath("$.id").saveAs("clientId")))

  setUp(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(200).during(180))).assertions(global.failedRequests.count.is(0))

  val sseConnection = scenario("ServerSentEvents")
    .exec { session =>
      sse("GET messages")
        .connect("/api/sse/" + session("clientId").as[String])
        .await(1)(
          sse.checkMessage("ConnectionCheck").matching(substring("connection established"))
            .check(bodyString.saveAs("InitialMessage"))
        )
    }
}
```

I would like to use the client ID saved into the Session in the first scenario, to configure the SSE endpoint to connect to in the second one. Presently, when running the scenario, I'm getting:

```
19:35:50.086 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - /home/dingo/Downloads/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.7.6/user-files/simulations/computerdatabase/SseSimulation.scala:21:15: type mismatch;
 found   : io.gatling.http.request.builder.sse.SseConnectRequestBuilder
 required: io.gatling.commons.validation.Validation[io.gatling.core.session.Session]
        .await(1)(
              ^
19:35:50.135 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - one error found
19:35:50.145 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - Compilation crashed
xsbt.InterfaceCompileFailed: null
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.handleErrors(CompilerBridge.scala:183)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerBridge.scala:172)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerBridge.scala:134)
    at xsbt.CompilerBridge.run(CompilerBridge.scala:39)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:91)
    at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$7(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:192)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
    at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:247)
    at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$4(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:182)
    at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$4$adapted(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:163)
    at sbt.internal.inc.JarUtils$.withPreviousJar(JarUtils.scala:239)
    at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:163)
    at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:210)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:528)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1$adapted(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:528)
    at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$apply$5(Incremental.scala:177)
    at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$apply$5$adapted(Incremental.scala:175)
    at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$$anon$2.run(Incremental.scala:461)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon$CycleState.next(IncrementalCommon.scala:116)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon$$anon$1.next(IncrementalCommon.scala:56)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon$$anon$1.next(IncrementalCommon.scala:52)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:263)
    at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$incrementalCompile$8(Incremental.scala:416)
    at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.withClassfileManager(Incremental.scala:503)
    at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.incrementalCompile(Incremental.scala:403)
    at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.apply(Incremental.scala:169)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileInternal(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:528)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileIncrementally$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:482)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:332)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: sbt.internal.inc.CompileFailed: Compilation failed
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:335)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:420)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compile(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:137)
    at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.doCompile(ZincCompiler.scala:218)
    at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.main(ZincCompiler.scala:226)
    at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler.main(ZincCompiler.scala)
```

How can I fix this?

Disclaimer: I don't know Scala.

Actions taken:

- Created a new folder structure for Gatling in my project
- Put the simulation class in `./src/gatling/java/computerdatabase`
- Put Stocks.json in `./src/gatling/resources/Stocks.json` and made the file path in the code absolute
- Added the [Gatling Gradle plugin](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/extensions/gradle_plugin/) to build.gradle
- Checked [this example Simulation](https://github.com/gatling/gatling-gradle-plugin-demo-java/blob/main/src/gatling/java/computerdatabase/BasicSimulation.java) for inspiration
- Fiddled around a bit with the code, reading about [Session function syntax](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/function/)

```
package computerdatabase;

import io.gatling.javaapi.core.ScenarioBuilder;
import io.gatling.javaapi.core.Simulation;
import io.gatling.javaapi.http.HttpProtocolBuilder;

import static io.gatling.javaapi.core.CoreDsl.*;
import static io.gatling.javaapi.http.HttpDsl.*;

public class SseSimulation extends Simulation {
    HttpProtocolBuilder httpProtocol = http
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:7070");

    ScenarioBuilder scn = scenario("Scenario Name")
            .exec(http("client id registration")
                    .post("/api/register/")
                    .body(RawFileBody("Stocks.json")).asJson()
                    .check(status().is(201))
                    .check(jsonPath("$.id").saveAs("clientId")))
            .exec(
                    sse("open channel")
                            .connect(session -> "/api/sse/" + session.getString("clientId"))
            );

    {
        setUp(scn.injectOpen(constantUsersPerSec(200).during(1)).protocols(httpProtocol)).assertions(global().failedRequests().count().is(0L));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Disclaimer: I don't know Scala.

Then switch to Java. Gatling 3.7 (that you're using) supports it as well and both the [official documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/) and the [official online courses](https://gatling.io/academy/) explain it very well.

Lots of things wrong:

- the code you've provided can't possibly compile. There's nothing named `scn` in there. Please fix it so one can help you.
- your compile error has nothing to do with the piece of code you've provided. The compiler complains about an error in `SseSimulation` while you've provided a class named `ssetest`. Again, please first fix your code sample
- `RawFileBody("./Stocks.json")` is wrong. You shouldn't use a relative path. Let the ClassLoader resolve your files. This `Stocks.json` file should go in `user-files/resources` and you should write `RawFileBody("Stocks.json")`
- Checks save data into the Session of the virtual user that executed the request. You can't use different scenarios because they would execute different sets of virtual users. You have to perform register and SSE connect in the same scenario.

I recommend that you should invest some time in reading the documentation and checking the online courses, you will ultimately save a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I added some other example by mistake. I was able to get started based on your feedback.